# using Instagram Private API

Tags: iphone, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to develop an iOS app integrate with Instagram.
I found that the official Instagram API not helping me very much so I discovered that there is a private API of instagram that I can do all the actions that I want.

I found Python library that use that API and its working but now I want to make a version for iOS using Swift.

I would like to know if there should be problems using that API on my iPhone Device with my Instagram Account I the legal aspect (Instagram can block my iPhone/account if I will use this API?)

Comment: did you integrate the api in your project man? needed bit of help.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram cannot block your iPhone/account.

They can only block particular APP if your app involved in malicious activity.

These are REST API, so this can support any platform. As long as you are doing legal things, there's no problem to use these API.

Comment: What do you define as a malicious activity?

Comment: Your app should follow rate limit conditions,  You need to submit your app to review with Instagram, Should not post porn or similar content. etc